# Swift call Python with PythonKit

Tags: python, ios, swift, swift-pythonkit

I want to call Python in Swift so I download a PythonKit and build it, but got the following error message. If I add the PythonKit dependency, it shows "Segmentation fault 11". Does anyone know how to resolve it? or any other way can call Python in Swift?

https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit

---

> swift run
>
> Compile Swift Module 'PythonKit' (4 sources)
>   /PythonKit-master/PythonKit/Python.swift:82:2: error: unknown
>   attribute 'dynamicCallable' @dynamicCallable  ^
>
> /PythonKit-master/PythonKit/Python.swift:82:2: error: unknown
>   attribute 'dynamicCallable' @dynamicCallable  ^
>
> /PythonKit-master/PythonKit/Python.swift:128:26: warning:
>   'CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable' is deprecated:
>   CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable will be removed in a future Swift
>   version. For customizing how types are presented in playgrounds, use
>   CustomPlaygroundDisplayConvertible instead. extension PythonObject :
>   CustomPlaygroundQuickLookable {

---

> If add
>
> ```
> .package(url: "https://github.com/pvieito/PythonKit.git", .branch("master"))
> ```
>
> It shows "Segmentation fault 11" when build.

---